# Why does row get thrown to bottom when updating table in PostgreSQL Python?

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I'm trying to update a table in PostgreSQL with Python, but there is something I don't quite get. The table contains 5 countries:

```
[(1,'Italy'), (2,'Poland'),(3,'South Korea'),(4,'Taiwan'),(5,'United States')]
```

When I update the table, say, replacing Poland with another country (e.g., Kazakhstan), the index shifts position to the bottom. So now you have:

```
[(1,'Italy'),(3,'South Korea'),(4,'Taiwan'),(5,'United States'),(2,'Poland')]
```

I also tried using ORDER BY, but then I get a syntax error. Why is that? And how can I maintain the index position?

Here is the code:

```
def update_countries():
    return ("""
                UPDATE countries
                SET country_name = 'Spain'
                WHERE country_id = 5;
             """)

conn = None
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        database = 'social',
        user = 'postgres',
        password = 'abc123',
        host = 'localhost',
        port = '5432')

    cur = conn.cursor()

    country_table = update_countries()
    cur.execute(country_table)
    print("[+] Data updated successfully!")
    conn.commit()

except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print('{}[-] Failed to connect.'.format(error))
    conn.rollback()
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Thank you in advance for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL tables have no order. Without an explicit ORDER BY in the SELECT statement, you are not even guaranteed the same order between two consecutive SELECT:s.

Comment: Hey, thanks for chiming in. Yeah, I was just reading about that. Also, apparently ORDER BY doesnt work with UPDATE, or does it? I tried adding it but it complains.
ORDER BY only with SELECT, yes?

Comment: ORDER BY does not work in an UPDATE statement because it would not make any sense, as the table has no order.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the table, it is very recommended to create it along with `indexing`. Indexes are used to retrieve the records from the database more quickly and more orderly.

Indexes might help you to return the records by a query in a specific sorted order (primary key is one way to do indexing). This allows a query's `ORDER BY` specification to be met without a separate sorting step. The one indexing method that can return sorted output in PostgreSQL is **B-Tree**.

Below is the example of creating indexing:

```
CREATE INDEX country_asc_index ON countries (country_id ASC);
```

---

REF:

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

[2] https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-ordering.html